# How to re-enable Unix Socket Authentication Plugin in Ubuntu and Debian GNU/Linux after Upgrading MariaDB 10.0

Tags: mariadb

I encountered this issue after upgrading from MariaDB 10.0.x to 10.2.x on Ubuntu, using the official MariaDB `apt` repos. (I suspect that Debian users will encounter the same.)

I was using MariaDB 10.0.x, with the `unix_socket` plugin, for quite some time, without issue, prior to this upgrade, which seems to suggest that the plugin was disabled, by default, in either Maria 10.0.x (and in a version later than the one I was using), 10.1.x or 10.2.x [citation needed].

What is the simplest means by which to re-enable the `unix_socket` plugin and continue allowing OS users to log into MariaDB accounts of the same name, without having to enter a password?

To be clear, I was able to log into MariaDB previously with the `mysql` command alone, as the `root` OS user (which is equivalent to `mysql -uroot`, without the plug-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of re-enabling the plug-in is straightforward, *provided you have root-level access to MariaDB*.

As any root-level MariaDB user, issue the following query (see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/ ):

```
INSTALL PLUGIN unix_socket SONAME 'auth_socket';
```

Then, restart the `mysql` (MariaDB) daemon; on Ubuntu or Debian:

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

MariaDB should behave as it did prior to version 10.0.22, with regard to the `unix_socket` plugin.

If your only root-level access to MariaDB prior to encountering this issue was through the `root` OS user, you may have to restart MariaDB in [Safe Mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqld_safe/) and set a password the root user, or, alternatively, create a secondary user with root-level privileges.

Once you're able to log into MariaDB with root-level privileges, you can execute the `INSTALL PLUGIN ...` command noted above. Don't forget to restart the daemon afterwards.